# Forcing multiple threads to use multiple CPUs when they are available

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading, multicore

I'm writing a Java program which uses a lot of CPU because of the nature of what it does.  However, lots of it can run in parallel, and I have made my program multi-threaded. When I run it, it only seems to use one CPU until it needs more then it uses another CPU - is there anything I can do in Java to force different threads to run on different cores/CPUs?

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you're asking, now that I think about it.  Are you asking (a)how to get it to run in multiple threads (b)why multithreaded code isn't using much more than one core or (c)Why the CPU load isn't evenly distributed?

Comment: Your application doesn't have enough tasks which can run independantly to use more than one CPU at a time.  The problem is highly unlikely to be in your OS as these have been tested by millions over many years.  You should look at your program again to see what tasks you expect to be running at the same time as try to determine what is stopping this happening.

Comment: Peter, if an app is running two threads, then it has enough things to be run on more than one core. Even if all the other thread does is start and terminate, there's still a workload available to run on the second core. -- For a single core to be divvied up between multiple threads just because each of them doesn't appear to have a high workload at the moment, is counter-productive. What about the idea of synchronizing to some off-CPU workload (such as a generic add-on compute board signaling it's finished w/its workload). Thread affinity is **extremely** important! Java should support this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> When I run it, it only seems to use
>   one CPU until it needs more then it
>   uses another CPU - is there anything I
>   can do in Java to force different
>   threads to run on different
>   cores/CPUs?

I interpret this part of your question as meaning that you have already addressed the problem of making your application multi-thread capable.  And despite that, it doesn't immediately start using multiple cores.

The answer to "is there any way to force ..." is (AFAIK) not directly.  Your JVM and/or the host OS decide how many 'native' threads to use, and how those threads are mapped to physical processors.  You do have some options for tuning.  For example, I found [this page](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/threads/threads.html) which talks about how to tune Java threading on Solaris.  And [this page](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/HotSpotFAQ.html#perf_scaling) talks about other things that can slow down a multi-threaded application.

Answer (score 62):

There are two basic ways to multi-thread in Java.  Each logical task you create with these methods should run on a fresh core when needed and available.

**Method one:** define a Runnable or Thread object (which can take a Runnable in the constructor) and start it running with the Thread.start() method. It will execute on whatever core the OS gives it -- generally the less loaded one.

Tutorial: [Defining and Starting Threads](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

**Method two:** define objects implementing the Runnable (if they don't return values) or Callable (if they do) interface, which contain your processing code.  Pass these as tasks to an ExecutorService from the java.util.concurrent package. The java.util.concurrent.Executors class has a bunch of methods to create standard, useful kinds of ExecutorServices. [Link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) to Executors tutorial.

From personal experience, the Executors fixed & cached thread pools are very good, although you'll want to tweak thread counts.  Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() can be used at run-time to count available cores.  You'll need to shut down thread pools when your application is done, otherwise the application won't exit because the ThreadPool threads stay running.

**Getting good multicore performance is sometimes tricky, and full of gotchas:**

- Disk I/O slows down a LOT when run in
  parallel. Only one thread should do disk read/write at a time.
- Synchronization of objects provides safety to multi-threaded operations, but slows down work.
- If tasks are too
  trivial (small work bits, execute
  fast) the overhead of managing them
  in an ExecutorService costs more than
  you gain from multiple cores.
- Creating new Thread objects is slow.  The ExecutorServices will try to re-use existing threads if possible.
- All sorts of crazy stuff can happen when multiple threads work on something.  Keep your system simple and try to make tasks logically distinct and non-interacting.

One other problem: controlling work is hard!  A good practice is to have one manager thread that creates and submits tasks, and then a couple working threads with work queues (using an ExecutorService).

I'm just touching on key points here -- multithreaded programming is considered one of the hardest programming subjects by many experts.  It's non-intuitive, complex, and the abstractions are often weak.

---

**Edit -- Example using ExecutorService:**

```
public class TaskThreader {
    class DoStuff implements Callable {
       Object in;
       public Object call(){
         in = doStep1(in);
         in = doStep2(in);
         in = doStep3(in); 
         return in;
       }
       public DoStuff(Object input){
          in = input;
       }
    }

    public abstract Object doStep1(Object input);    
    public abstract Object doStep2(Object input);    
    public abstract Object doStep3(Object input);    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        ArrayList<Callable> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable>();
        for(Object input : inputs){
           tasks.add(new DoStuff(input));
        }
        List<Future> results = exec.invokeAll(tasks);
        exec.shutdown();
        for(Future f : results) {
           write(f.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I went and read more about the topic because I was not clear about the advantage of the Executors. I am not yet sure about the others but the `FixedThreadPool` seems great because it limits the number of threads running (1) avoiding overloads of changing tasks, and (2) making sure that some threads finish first (and getting some results quick). This is specially useful for running experiments.

Answer (score 20):

First, you should prove to yourself that your program would run *faster* on multiple cores. Many operating systems put effort into running program threads on the same core *whenever possible*.

Running on the same core has many advantages. The CPU cache is hot, meaning that data for that program is loaded into the CPU. The lock/monitor/synchronization objects are in CPU cache which means that other CPUs do not need to do cache synchronization operations across the bus (expensive!).

One thing that can very easily make your program run on the same CPU all the time is over-use of locks and shared memory. Your threads should not talk to each other. The less often your threads use the same objects in the same memory, the more often they will run on different CPUs. The more often they use the same memory, the more often they must block waiting for the other thread.

Whenever the OS sees one thread block for another thread, it will run that thread on the same CPU whenever it can. It reduces the amount of memory that moves over the inter-CPU bus. That is what I guess is causing what you see in your program.

Answer (score 8):

First, I'd suggest reading ["Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

[image]

This is by far the best book describing concurrent java programming.

Concurrency is 'easy to learn, difficult to master'.  I'd suggest reading plenty about the subject before attempting it.  It's very easy to get a multi-threaded program to work correctly 99.9% of the time, and fail 0.1%.  However, here are some tips to get you started:

There are two common ways to make a program use more than one core:

1. Make the program run using multiple processes.  An example is Apache compiled with the Pre-Fork MPM, which assigns requests to child processes.  In a multi-process program, memory is not shared by default.  However, you can map sections of shared memory across processes.  Apache does this with it's 'scoreboard'.
2. Make the program multi-threaded.  In a multi-threaded program, all heap memory is shared by default.  Each thread still has it's own stack, but can access any part of the heap.  Typically, most Java programs are multi-threaded, and not multi-process.

At the lowest level, one can [create and destroy threads](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).  Java makes it easy to create threads in a portable cross platform manner.

As it tends to get expensive to create and destroy threads all the time, Java now includes [Executors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to create re-usable thread pools.  Tasks can be assigned to the executors, and the result can be retrieved via a Future object.

Typically, one has a task which can be divided into smaller tasks, but the end results need to be brought back together.  For example, with a merge sort, one can divide the list into smaller and smaller parts, until one has every core doing the sorting.  However, as each sublist is sorted, it needs to be merged in order to get the final sorted list.  Since this is "divide-and-conquer" issue is fairly common, there is a [JSR framework](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/) which can handle the underlying distribution and joining.  This framework will likely be included in Java 7.

Comment: The JSR 166y framework has been included in Java 7 in the java.util.concurrent package's classes ForkJoinPool and ForkJoinTask http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to set CPU affinity in Java. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4234402

If you have to do it, use JNI to create native threads and set their affinity.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is break your program into multiple processes.  The OS will allocate them across the cores.

Somewhat harder is to break your program into multiple threads and trust the JVM to allocate them properly.  This is -- generally -- what people do to make use of available hardware.

---

**Edit**

How can a multi-processing program be "easier"?   Here's a step in a pipeline.

```
public class SomeStep {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        BufferedReader stdin= new BufferedReader( System.in );
        BufferedWriter stdout= new BufferedWriter( System.out );
        String line= stdin.readLine();
        while( line != null ) {
             // process line, writing to stdout
             line = stdin.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Each step in the pipeline is similarly structured.  9 lines of overhead for whatever processing is included.

This may not be the absolute most efficient.  But it's very easy.

---

The overall structure of your concurrent processes is not a JVM problem.  It's an OS problem, so use the shell.

```
java -cp pipline.jar FirstStep | java -cp pipline.jar SomeStep | java -cp pipline.jar LastStep
```

The only thing left is to work out some serialization for your data objects in the pipeline.
Standard Serialization works well.  Read http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/ for hints on how to serialize.  You can replace the `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` with `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to accomplish this.

Comment: How would a multi-process application be *easier* to implement than a multi-threaded one?

Comment: @Michael: I agree with you, but this is subject to debate. The advantages of processes is that they are entirely separated, so you have to do extra effort in order to make them communicate -- which means that if a process crashes, others processes may recover more easily.

Comment: multi-process application done via a GNU/Linux pipeline is trivial.  Linux scripts do this all the time with almost no effort.  Read from stdin, write to stdout and it will use cores effectively.

Comment: @S. Lott: I can't find a trivial way to use this when, say, a server uses a process/thread for each client, and shares data structures which can be modified by any process/thread.

Comment: Most "shared" data structures are read frequently and updated rarely.  Enqueue update requests to a DB-writer process, but read the source file(s) directly as needed.  This is very simple to implement.

Comment: I would agree if this were C, but not for java. Java's handling of streams is slow due to synchronization, and its stdin/stdout I/O is a pain to work with.  If this were a NIX C or C++ program, this would be the way to go.  Java offers good synchronization/multithreading tools though, so why not use them?

Comment: The other issue with doing process parallelism is that IPC is platform-specific.  He said he's implementing this in Java, and if you start using platform-specific IPC you're going to lose portability.  Not that threading in Java is completely portable, but IPC between JVMs can be nasty.  I've seen projects use sockets to avoid inter-JVM IPC, and at that point you're paying a lot to get what you could've done quite easily with threads.

Comment: Not sure multiple processes will necessarily help anyway-- depending on your OS, it probably schedules at thread level anyway.

Comment: "Java offers good synchronization/multithreading tools"  True.  The point is that reading System.stdin and writing System.stdout is easier.  Not faster.  Easier.

Comment: @Lott: that doesn't do you much good if your goal is performance though, does it?  You're basically making a slower version of a message passing interface.  

I agree with separating processing stages, but why do it via Stream when you can use work queues and worker threads?

Comment: @BobMcGee: The unix pipeline isn't a "slower" version of a message passing interface.  Try it.  It's shared buffers and runs at an amazingly fast speed.  You can use Queues and Workers, but it's not as simple.  The point is that reading System.stdin and writing System.stdout is easier. Not faster. Easier.

Comment: @Lott Again, fast only in C -- the issue is Java's stream I/O being synchronized and checked on every I/O call, not the pipeline.  Nor is it easier-- if you use stdout/stdin you need to define a communications protocol and work with parsing potentially.  Don't forget exceptions writing into the StdOut too! Using a manager thread, ExecutorServices, and Runnable/Callable tasks is much simpler to implement.  It's do-able in <100 lines of very simple code (with error checking), potentially very fast, and performs well.

Comment: @Lott:  Look, see my code?  It's longer, but it provides the complete application structure (minus input and output), and THREE steps. Your code gives a **ONE** step worker. It doesn't provide for task creation or overall process handling.  You didn't specify communications protocol between processes, how multiple processes get started or communications set up or anything.  How is your code still easier?

Comment: @BobMcGee: It's easier because unix folks have been doing it this way for 40 years.  There are numerous widely established precedents for doing it this way.  The protocol for passing messages is -- 80% of the time -- simple serialization.  The other 20% it's a simple text stream.  The point is to be easier.

Comment: @BobMcGee: "Your code gives a ONE step worker" Correct.  They're all identical, so providing the other two seems specious to me.  I could copy and paste two other clones, if you think that clarifies things.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this answer more than once.  The question is about multithreaded programs, and you're putting forth stdin/stdout as some kind of general model of parallelism.  This is a good approach for command-line tools that only need a FIFO, but it gets complicated if you have to transport anything of significance over the pipe.  There are plenty of data structures in java.util.concurrent for exactly this kind of thing.  They aren't hard to use if all you need is a pipeline, and you don't need to serialize, spawn multiple JVMs, or any of that to use them.

Comment: @Tgamplin: Agreed.  I probably should drop the argument because it is obvious.
@SLott: They're not identical -- you haven't provided code to set up the system, spawn and manage the processes or implement a messaging format to communicate tasks and pass out work / receive results and errors.  UNIX does it this way because it made sense at the time & because multiple cores weren't that common.  The "One Task One Program" philosophy also predominated.  Java provides better concurrency primitives, and that approach is silly; why use IPC when the VM provides all you need?

Comment: @BobMcGee: Agreed.  They're not identical.  Pipelines can be simpler because most of what you need is already provided.  Protocol is serialization.  Pipeline construction is allocated to the shell.  Errors go to stderr.  It's simple.  Not equivalent.  Not better.  Simple.

Comment: @Lott: Perhaps you could flesh out your example to include more complete structure?  That is to say, provide the main method, with process creation and destruction + very basic Serialized object communication for job start/end.   I'd really like to see what the final code looks like, since I'm not as familiar with process-level concurrency.  I think process parallelism should lend itself well to data-flow programming, which works better with concurrency than procedural.  I'd just like to see the comparable structure.   Also, maybe we should make a commmunity wiki post to discuss this?

Comment: @Lott: on anything but the latest Java releases from Sun, VM startup overhead is going to eat your performance if you use it like that.  Simple, yes, but I thought you had a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @BobMcGee: VM startup is only a penalty if your workload is poorly designed and spends a lot of time starting subprocesses.  If your workload is well-designed, your processes run for so long that startup overhead is amortized over long running times.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your program to do its work in the form of a *lot* of Callable's handed to an ExecutorService and executed with invokeAll(...).

You can then choose a suitable implementation at runtime from the Executors class.  A suggestion would be to call Executors.newFixedThreadPool() with a number roughly corresponding to the number of cpu cores to keep busy.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is related to Java Parallel Proccesing Framework (JPPF). Using this you can run diferent jobs on diferent processors.

Answer (score 1):

JVM performance tuning has been mentioned before in [Why does this Java code not utilize all CPU cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867278/why-does-this-java-code-not-utilize-all-cpu-cores/2867731#2867731). Note that this only applies to the JVM, so your application must already be using threads (and more or less "correctly" at that):

http://ch.sun.com/sunnews/events/2009/apr/adworkshop/pdf/5-1-Java-Performance.pdf

Comment: +1 for the reference. The link to PDF seems to be broken. Can you share the title if you still have that PDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below API from [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--) with Java 8 version

```
public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
```

> Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.

Due to work stealing mechanism, idle threads steal tasks from task queue of busy threads and overall throughput will increase.

From [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java/?v=source), implementation of `newWorkStealingPool` is as follows

```
/**
     * Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all
     * {@link Runtime#availableProcessors available processors}
     * as its target parallelism level.
     * @return the newly created thread pool
     * @see #newWorkStealingPool(int)
     * @since 1.8
     */
    public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool() {
        return new ForkJoinPool
            (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
             ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,
             null, true);
    }
```