# Java Huge Thread Pool performance issues

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool

I need to create a tons of threads to do some processing on data. and there are few performance issues. Any suggestions on how this code could be improved are welcome.

Inputs to the thread are a string and a list of data. List size is around 1 million custom objects. The data from list is processed by each thread according to inputted string of data. Individual tasks do not update anything to the list. they just take the data and process the data as required. Disk utilization is hardly 3-5%, which isnt a bottleneck. MySQL has been tuned accordingly to ensure maximum performance.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor lt_segThreadExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) 
                                            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(28);

int counter = 0; 
for (String temp : lc_Data){
    ++counter; 
    lt_segThreadExecutor.execute(new SegregateData (temp,                                                            lc_Data) ); // Inputs are java containers. A list. Nothing is modified by any threads. List size is around 1 million entries. 
    if ((counter % (size / 10)) == 0 ){
        System.out.println("Completed processing for : " + counter + " % of data");
    }
}


lt_segThreadExecutor.shutdown();
try {
    lt_segThreadExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception Occured.");
}
```

I am using a threadpool with Fixed Size. Yes there are 28 physical cores. The total number of tasks that need completion are around 50-75 thousands. So, the loop would go on for almost 50 to 75K.

There are no sysout's in the threads. Threads do not write anything to any logfile as such. They make an entry to DB. DB is on a NVME SSD. So, there is no waiting for resources between threads. All tasks are independent. Each process data based on the parameter value passed.

Problem:
This code takes ~44 Minutes on a quad Core I7 machine. It takes ~32 minutes on a server with 28 cores. 
Available mem : 16 Gigs usable.
Increased the xms size to 8 gigs. Still there is no improvement. CPU stands at ~95% utilization. resources are abundant. but the performance is not as expected. Checked disk utilization, there is no bottleneck there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Profile** your code. Look for a better algorithm. Remember [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law). There isn't enough here to offer more advice.

Comment: You're confusing a lot of things here. If you create a fixed thread pool of size 28, then there are 28 threads, not tons of threads, not around 50-75 thousands of threads. 28. Those threads can execute many *tasks* though. If all CPU cores are 100% busy, there's not much you can do except making your algorithm more efficient.

Comment: Sorry! didnt clarify clearly regarding the tasks and threads. Surely there is something, that i am missing, Core I7 has a marginal improvement in completing all of the tasks. The i7 has just 4 cores, where as the server has 7X more and etc. the difference between both machines is not much.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: We don't have any idea of what the tasks are doing. Maybe they all compete for shared data, memory, disk?

Comment: You need to provide far more context (and clarify "thread" vs. "task" throughout your question). It's perfectly reasonable for tens of threads to handle tens-of-thousands of tasks, so if you're seeing surprisingly poor performance there's likely a bottleneck in *your code*, not an issue with the thread pool.

Comment: Updated the question. Added more comments related to the number of entries being processed in the thread. Input to the thread is a list comprising of 1 million or more custom objects. These are fetched from DB.

Comment: I've voted to close this as unclear given that it's not solvable with the information you've provided.

Comment: If you provided the whole code of `SegregateData`, or more generally, an [MCVE], then people *might* actually dig into this and spot the bottleneck - but it would still hardly be suited for a "Q&A" site.

Comment: Why don't you try a CPU profiler to find out the bottlenecks? You may also want to visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867278/why-does-this-java-code-not-utilize-all-cpu-cores