# Multithreaded Java does not speed up

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented a simple parallel merge sort algorithm in Java. This cuts the array into equal sections and passes them to be sorted independently by each thread. After the array segments are sorted, they are merged by a single thread. Because there are no shared resources, so no synchronization is used when the sub lists are sorted. The last thread which merges the result array though waits for the other threads to complete.

When two threads are used there is performance gain almost 66%. When I use 4 threads, then the time taken does not differ from the 2 threads version. I am on linux `2.6.40.6-0.fc15.i686.PAE`, and an Intel Core i5 .

I am benchmarking time with the unix `time` command (array is assigned uniform random integers). At the end of the sorting I am checking if the array ordering is correct or not (not parallel).

1 Thread

```
$ echo "100000000" | time -p java mergeSortTest

Enter n: 
[SUCCESS]

real 40.73
user 40.86
sys 0.22
```

2 Threads

```
$ echo "100000000" | time -p java mergeSortTest

Enter n: 
[SUCCESS]

real 26.90
user 49.65
sys 0.48
```

4 Threads

```
$ echo "100000000" | time -p java mergeSortTest

Enter n: 
[SUCCESS]

real 25.13
user 76.53
sys 0.43
```

The CPU usage is around 80% to 90% when using 4 threads, and around 50% when using 2 threads, and around 25% when using single thread.

I was expecting some speedup when run in 4 threads. Am I wrong anywhere.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the code: [http://pastebin.com/9hQPhCa8](http://pastebin.com/y0gmaDCA)

**UPDATE 2**
I have a Intel Core i5 second generation processor.

Output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | less` (only core 0 is shown).

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 3072 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4589.60
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Core i5 only has two physical cores doesn't it?

Comment: The precise way you implement your algo could also influence this.

Comment: CPU information tells that it has 4 cores. (have to check the manual).

Comment: @trojanfoe - The published specs (http://ark.intel.com/products/52207/Intel-Core-i5-2400-Processor-(6M-Cache-3_10-GHz)) say 4 cores.

Comment: @Ted Hopp  Some Core i5 have 4 cores and some have only 2 cores.

Comment: @Mat in case of 4 threads, the list is first divided into 4 independent lists and sorted independently, therefore i am expecting some speedup when compared to a 2 thread implementation.

Comment: I don't think all Core i5's are the same though - older ones had 2 physical cores and 2 hyper-threaded cores.  You need to determine which Core i5 you are using.

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and check the `siblings` and `cpu cores` values; if they are different then you have hyper-threaded cores.

Comment: The described CPU usage is coherent with the 4 cores hypothesis.

Comment: Even with a quad-core, you may not notice any improvement unless the input array is long enough so that the time spent in the parallel sortings is greater by far than the final merge process.

Comment: @trojanfoe: you are right, the `cores` and `siblings` are different, i am updating the question with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @TedHopp - The published specs(http://ark.intel.com/products/52224) say 2 cores.

Comment: Yes, my processor is actually http://ark.intel.com/products/52224 and therefore 2 physical cores and 4 threads. This justifies the output times.

Comment: Then shouldn't the CPU usage be around 90% to 100% when running 2 threads?

Comment: Beware of the dangers of naive microbenchmarking. To claim that some program outperforms some other by X%, you really have to run a lot of tests for different input sizes and machine configurations. A good paper written by Goetz here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html

Comment: @MisterSmith: just a rough bench, very few different sized inputs, definitely nothing definite. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Are you using the same input array of elements to do your bench marking? If you don't you will have skewed results, just because an algorithm runs within a given O() that doesn't mean there won't be some variance in worst case scenarios.

Comment: @icirellik: not the same input arrays, but  taking multiple runs on randomly generated arrays on a single thread the time taken is approximately the same, as it should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Core i5 has 2 cores and hyperthreading technology so it seems that it has 4 cores. Those extra two logical cores will not help nearly as much as two physical cores since your sorting algorithm does a good job at keeping the CPU busy.

Since you asked for a "credible" source, I will point to an article from the Intel website that I read a while back: [performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology/). In particular note the following section on "limitations of hyperthreading":

> **Extremely compute-efficient applications.** If the processor's execution
>   resources  are already well utilized, then there is little to be
>   gained by enabling Intel  HT Technology. For instance, code that
>   already can execute four instructions per  cycle will not increase
>   performance when running with Intel HT Technology  enabled, as the
>   process core can only execute a maximum of four instructions  per
>   cycle.

Also note this section about the memory subsystem contention:

> **Extremely high memory bandwidth applications.** Intel HT Technology increases the  demand placed on the memory subsystem when running two
>   threads. If an application  is capable of utilizing all the memory
>   bandwidth with Intel HT Technology  disabled, then the performance
>   will not increase when Intel HT Technology is  enabled. It is possible
>   in some circumstances that performance will degrade, due  to increased
>   memory  demands and/or data caching effects in these instances. The 
>   good news is that systems based on the Nehalem core with integrated
>   memory  controllers and Intel® QuickPath Interconnects greatly
>   increase available memory   bandwidth compared to older Intel CPUs
>   with Intel HT technology. The result is  that the number of
>   applications that will experience a degradation using Intel HT 
>   Technology on the Nehalem core due to lack of memory bandwidth is
>   greatly reduced.

Other interesting points can be found in the [Intel Guide for Developing Multithreaded Applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-guide-for-developing-multithreaded-applications/). Here is another snippet from [detecting-memory-bandwidth-saturation-in-threaded-applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/detecting-memory-bandwidth-saturation-in-threaded-applications/):

> As an increasing number of threads or processes share the limited
>   resources of  cache capacity and memory bandwidth, the scalability of
>   a threaded application  can become constrained. Memory-intensive
>   threaded applications can suffer from  memory bandwidth saturation as
>   more threads are introduced. In such cases, the  threaded application
>   won’t scale as expected, and performance can be reduced.

Comment: as per @Peters Lawrey core i7 also did not any performance gain, how can this be described.

Comment: The core i7 has 4 cores but they are most likely competing over a single memory bus, this can also hinder performance. I've also added a quote about this in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

The [intel core i5-xxM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5) series has 2 cores so using more than 2 threads will reduce performance due to more context switching.

**Edit:**

Here is an expansion on my answer where I take up [Core i7 architecture](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/corei7/319724.pdf)-specific factors that may affect the performance of a CPU and memory intensive operations such as a sort.

**Turbo boost technology**

Intel Core i7 has variable processor frequency. At high loads, the frequency will be limited by heat, reducing the performance gain of utilising more cores.

**Shared L3 cache**

Sorting large data sets (>>8 Mb) will result in a lot of L3 page faults. Using too many threads may increase the number of page faults, decreasing efficiency. I'm not sure if that is the case for a mergesort. (BTW: how do you measure L3 cache misses in Linux?)
I am not sure this is a factor, though.

I must say that I am surprised that you don't get any performance boost from using all four cores of the i7. I'll try to run some tests at home this weekend.

Comment: Just note that this statement is not true in general. It is true only for CPU bound processes. For instance, if you are doing some IO polling, you can improve a lot overall performance by adding threads more than the number of available cores.

Comment: Also his specific processor may have 2 cores, but it has support for 4 concurrent threads. [Details here](http://ark.intel.com/products/52224)

Comment: @icirellik Unless he disabled HT in the BIOS.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible issue might be false sharing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=217500206

This would depend on how often merge sort accesses elements in the boundary cache lines. This would probably be much more noticeable on data sets smaller than a kilobyte or so.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on the i7 and even with 4 cores there was no improvement from 2 - 4 threads.  I suspect the problem is that your data doesn't fit in cache so you are testing the throughput of the single memory bus.

Comment: @phoxis: looks like your i5 has 2 L2 cache (one per core) and a shared L3 cache, which might allow 2 threads to have a good cache hit that maps well to predicted memory access while 4 threads could end up spending a lot of overhead on cache misses.  As for Peter and the i7, not sure of the model, but, probably has 4 L2 caches with the shared L3, which I would expect to see better performance at 4 threads - maybe it is 4 core with 8 hyper threads and the work is ending up with 2 threads on a core causing the same L2 thrash that you might see on the i5. Peter, maybe try 8 threads?

Comment: 2 threads was about 70% faster than 1, but 4, 8 and 16 was all the same.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting about the expected result on a dual core i7 with -server JVM option, 100000000 ints and 2GB Xmx memory:

1 thread: 23 seconds
2 threads: 14 seconds
4 threads: 10 seconds

And I also removed the manual garbage collection, and execute the sorts in sequence within the same JVM instance, having a warmup sort first.

As Mister Smith comments, microbenchmarking (JVM hotspot) is somewhat complex, and I might add that for 4+ cores, the merge sort could be performed by half the number of threads opposed to on a single thread as now, so your benchmark is not totally true to the multi-threading approach.

You might also want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223072/how-do-i-optimize-for-multi-core-and-multi-cpu-computers-in-java) question.

Answer (score 2):

As a comparison, try using merge sort with java 7 and the fork join framework.  There is an example of how to do that [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03048/index.html).  This will show you if it is a problem with your implementation, or a limitation of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting because I have the same observation in trying to parallelise merge sort. Tried two different work spawning approaches but did not get a speed up. My approach to parallelise merge sort is to make the merging parallel. and do individual merges on different cores? In this case, the recursion cut off and number of threads affect the speed up. Again the speed up cannot overrun serial speed. This technique appears in Structured Parallel programming Patterns and Practices book from Morgan Kaufman.

[A parallel merge sort](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2012/08/go-parallel.html)

Answer (score 0):

i recently had to do a papper comparing bubble sort, merge sort and bitonic sort on i7 architecture. I used the first code given here for the merge and had the same problem: 8threads were no better than 4. Then i read SMT (intel hyperthreading) stuff and found out the problem and the solution:

**Remove this lines on the merge method:**

> if (Runtime.getRuntime (). freeMemory () < ((n1 + n2) * 4))
>             Runtime.getRuntime (). gc ();

This code frees the memory con L1 and L2 levels of the physical cores, but in those kbs we have the buffers for two logic threads (not only one), therefore one thread erases the buffer of the sibling thread in that phys core.

After removing that *if*, i saw the 1.25 improvement between 4 and 8 threads that SMT provides.
If someone can try this on an i5 that would be great.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit the above to remove the several errors.