# .Net 4.0 code will run on Core 2 Duo but not i5. Advice needed

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-7, cross-platform, cpu

I have written some very complex multithreaded code. It uses spinning, yields, and the Interlocked library.

The code runs flawlessly on my Core 2 Duo 2 GHz machine. On my i5 2.4 GHz dual core quad thread machine, it is slow (as in slower than the Core 2), or totally fails to run (simply sits at 0% CPU).

Both machines have Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit and the .Net 4.5 framework. My dev machine is the Core 2 Duo. I developed in Visual Studio 2011 Dev Preview. The code is compiled with optimizations on.

I cannot paste the multiple lines of code here. Can anyone even begin to tell me why this could be happening / what to look for in my code. I am a little shocked at this outcome from a .Net assembly.

**EDIT**

I tested the speed of MS's BlockingCollection, and that too was a fraction of the speed on the i5, but the 4 "cores" were all 100% = some type of race condition. However, here I am simply calling the TryAdd() / Take() methods with no spinning or any other type of thread control on my part.

Comment: Reduce the code to the absolute minimum until the problem disappears. Then show us the code.

Comment: The code is at its absolute minimum, which is not exactly a few lines. Removing any part would stop the whole thing from doing anything. This is not going to be fun.

Comment: A standard bug in multi-threaded code is a race condition.  A standard way to trip such a bug is by altering the execution timing.

Comment: Hans, true. I'm using SpinWait with Interlocked.CompareExchange, which means as far as I know that I should be free of race condition issues.

Comment: 'spinning', 'yields' ...   I'm in favour of using only kernel synchro objects to write multiThreaded apps initially, (that, and only message-passing).  'spinning' should be left as a performance optimization, if required, once the bottlenecks in the first, kernel-locked, version has been soak-tested at max. load for days without deadlocks, leaks or any other anomalous behaviour apart from being too slow overall.  Never, ever used yield(), sleep(0), sleep(1) or found the slightest inclination to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is extremely likely that you are experiencing a race condition. The symptoms are all there- you have complex threading code that either doesn't run or doesn't run the way you expect it should, and the behavior varies across machines. The fact that it runs on the dual core box doesn't prove that the code is race free...  More cores means a higher likelihood that subtle races will show up.

In short, we need the code to help.

You mention that you are using "spinning class"- do you mean SpinLock and SpinWait?

Comment: I am using SpinLock in combination with Interlocked.CompareExchange. While that may create a race condition, I believe it is the most efficient way of doing what I'm doing (backed up by the albahari tutorial on this type of code & MSDN). However, the CPU goes to 0, which means nothing is happening. That is unexplainable.

Comment: @Chris Shain: I think a deadlock is more likely to put the CPU at 0%, not a data race.

Comment: Yes, but he says sometimes it works (slowly) and sometimes it doesnt. That screams race to me. Maybe a race that can cause a deadlock for sure.

Comment: @IanC, interlocked.compareexchange is atomic, no need to lock just for that.

Comment: Chris, I know. I am only using locks for Monitor.Pulse and Monitor.Wait.

Comment: @IanC: These two methods are a frequent cause of deadlock. If no thread is waiting on Wait, then the signal of Pulse is lost. You may have a timing bug here. Try replacing them with an AutoresetEvent.

Comment: Tudor, that could be. However, I tried some similar code which doesn't use these methods, and the problem still exists. Also, I put special tracers on those methods and the numbers correlate 100%.

Comment: I had plenty of stalls using those methods until I got that part of the code working.

Answer (score 2):

Without any code, I can only speculate:

The Core i5 is known to have Intel hyperthreading technology which brings the number of hardware threads to 4 with only 2 cores, so you effectively have four threads competing for the same CPU functional units. This means that compute intensive applications or applications that need a lot of memory bandwidth may suffer a performance degradation when used on CPUs with HT technology. Try to fix the number of threads spawned by your application to 2 (such that you are effectively not using the HT feature) and see if it runs like on the original dual core.

Also check this article for features and weaknesses of HT: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology/

And this (somewhat) related SO question: [Multithreaded Java does not speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138245/multithreaded-java-does-not-speed-up)

Comment: The code won't even run with 2 threads. I am using MS's spinning class, which MSDN states is specifically designed to overcome HT weaknesses. I'll check out the articles you linked to and see if that helps.

Comment: @IanC: You may have a deadlock then.

Comment: Hans, I ran a much simpler version of my code and MS's BlockingCollection. Both completed, but with full CPU usage and in terrible time. I obsiously don't use any thread control with the BlockingCollection, which means the problem (at least in this case), is probably outside my code.

Comment: @IanC: So does you app exhibit any of the characteristics that are mentioned in that article to affect the performance on hyperthreading CPUs?