# Are parallel drawing operations possible with Java Graphics2d?

Tags: java, graphics, parallel-processing

I've a little test here to demonstrate the problem.

Obviously the code works but as you increase the thread count (assuming there are enough cores) performance does not improve.

It's as if drawing operations are serialised.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class Para2dTest {

class DrawSomething implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random r = new Random();

        long start = new Date().getTime();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( 100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            Color c = new Color( r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256) );
            g2d.setPaint(c);
            g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
        }
        g2d.dispose();

        long end = new Date().getTime();

        System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + ( end - start ) );
    }
}

public Para2dTest( int threads ) {

    for ( int t = 0; t < threads; t++ ) {
        Thread ds = new Thread( new DrawSomething() );
        ds.start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");

    int threads = 16;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            threads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Processing with " + threads + " threads");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Argument" + " must be an integer");
        }
    }

    new Para2dTest( threads );
}
}
```

Comment: This is a specific version of the [many times asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223072/how-do-i-optimize-for-multi-core-and-multi-cpu-computers-in-java) general question about whether the coder can control how threads are processed on a multi-core system.

Comment: There is a big lock in AWT. (Was as intrinsic lock but was changed to a `Lock` in JDK 6 for performance reasons, at almost exactly the same time as the HotSpot levelled it's lock with jucl.) I think that may come into play here.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll look into the open jdk source and see if anything can be done.

Comment: Sure enough every method locks with SunToolkit.awtLock();

Answer (score 0):

What I seen from given code, that you are execute in threads separate "jobs". Each threads create "his own" BufferedImage and draw something.

So, regarding your question:

- if you want to draw quickly by paralleling/concurrent execution, you will need to share BufferedImage or Graphics* reference between threads.

Comment: Actually as mentioned by Tom Hawtin above the problem is that all drawing operations that go through AWT use a single global lock.