# multi threading in java in computational speed up

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using multi threading in this program. I am new to this concept and I have used what I have learned from internet, but it is not working properly. Can you please help me in a way to utilize all CPU cores so I can compute this as much fast as possible.

```
package percolate;

public class Multithread implements Runnable
{


    static int col =10000;
    int m=8;
    int n=3;
    static int row=10000;
            int count=0;
    double p=Math.PI,t=Math.sqrt(3),pi=(p/(col+1));
    double mul,a,b,c,d,e,f,xx,yy;
     static int[][] matrix = new int [row][col];
      static int[][] label = new int [row][col];

     public Multithread(Object a,Object b) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         sin1((int) a,(int) b);
     }
     public Multithread() 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        eqltri();
         operation();
         outputt();
    }

        private void sin1(int start,int row)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method 
            for (int i =start; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
                {
                    xx=((i+1)*pi);
                    yy=((j+1)*pi);
                    a=Math.cos(((2*m)-n)*((2*(xx))/3));
                    b=Math.sin(((2*(n*(yy)))/t));
                    c=Math.cos(((((2*n)-m)*(2*(xx)))/3));
                    d=Math.sin(((2*m)*(yy)/t));
                    e=Math.cos((((m+n)*(2*(xx)))/3));
                    f=Math.sin((((m-n)*(2*(yy)))/t));

                       mul=(a*b)-(c*d)+(e*f);

                    if(mul<0 && (xx*t)>yy&& yy<(t*(p-xx)))
                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=1;
                    }
                //System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                //System.out.println();
            }

        } 
        private void eqltri()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
                {
                    xx=(i+1)*pi;
                    yy=(j+1)*pi;
                    if((xx*t)>yy&& yy<(t*(p-xx)))

                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    matrix[i][j]=4; 
                    }
                    //System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                //System.out.println();
            }

        }
        private void operation()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) 
                {
                    if(i==0 && j==0)
                    {
                        count=count+1;
                        label[i][j]=count;
                    }
                    else if (((i-1)>=0) && j==0) 
                    {
                        left(i,j);  
                    }
                    else if (((j-1)>=0)&& i==0)
                    {
                        above(i,j);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    aboveleft(i,j); 
                    }
                }

            }




        }

        private void left(int a,int b)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(matrix[a-1][b]==matrix[a][b])
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
            }
            else
            {
                count=count+1;
                label[a][b]=count;
            }

        }
        private void above(int a,int b) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (matrix[a][b-1]==matrix[a][b])
              {
                  label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
              }
              else
              {
                count=count+1;
                label[a][b]=count;
              }
        }
        private void aboveleft(int a,int b)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (matrix[a][b-1]==matrix[a][b] && matrix[a-1][b]!=matrix[a][b])
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
            }
            else if (matrix[a-1][b]==matrix[a][b] && matrix[a][b-1]!=matrix[a][b])
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
            }
            else if (matrix[a][b-1]!=matrix[a][b] && matrix[a-1][b]!=matrix[a][b])
            {
                count=count+1;
                label[a][b]=count;
            }
            else
            {
                checklabel(a, b);
            }

        }
        private void checklabel(int a, int b)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(label[a-1][b]>label[a][b-1])
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a][b-1];
                int neww=label[a][b-1];
                int old=label[a-1][b];
                nonzero(old,neww);
                backtrace(old);
                count=count-1;
            }
            else if (label[a-1][b]==label[a][b-1])
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];

            }
            else
            {
                label[a][b]=label[a-1][b];
                int neww=label[a-1][b];
                int old=label[a][b-1];
                nonzero(old,neww);
                backtrace(old);
                count=count-1;
            }

        }
        private void nonzero(int ol,int nw)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    if (label[i][j]==ol)
                    {

                        label[i][j]=nw;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        private void backtrace(int a)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
            {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if(label[i][j]>a )
                {
                    label[i][j]=(label[i][j])-1;
                }
            }   
            }

        }
        private void outputt() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("hello its error");
            /*for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                }
            System.out.println();
            }*/
            System.out.println(count-1);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Multithread n1=new Multithread(0,5000);
        Multithread n3=new Multithread(5000,10000);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(n1);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(n3);
        t1.start();
        t3.start();
        Multithread n=new Multithread();
System.out.println("Number of active threads from the given thread: " + Thread.activeCount());


    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

}
```

The main objective is to fill an array of about 10 million elements after performing some trigonometric computations and for that thing only I want multi threading. Please help!!

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223072/forcing-multiple-threads-to-use-multiple-cpus-when-they-are-available?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Use fork and Join using fork join pool, AFAIK that will give best result; you cannot force jvm to use all threads that depends on OS etc

Comment: You can see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html